# Prevent xmlns="" attribute from being added to HTML elements generated by XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces, phpdoc

I am in the process of creating a template for phpdoc 2 and I am trying to figure out how to prevent the attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` from being added to the root level elements of the generated HTML when the documentation is created from my template. My .xsl files in the template generate files containing html fragments, which is why the `<html>` tag is not the root level element. It appears phpdoc 2 uses XSLT v1.0, so that limits my options a bit. After doing some searching, the most common answer was to use the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute on the `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag of each .xsl file, and set its value to either `#all` or `#default`, since you cannot just use `xmlns` as a namespace to exclude directly. But I tried that, setting the `exclude-result-prefixes` on every .xsl file in my template, and it did not work.

As requested, here's one of one of my .xsl files, api-doc.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:output indent="no" method="html"/>

    <xsl:include href="chrome.xsl"/>

    <xsl:include href="api-doc/property.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="api-doc/class.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="api-doc/constant.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="api-doc/function.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="api-doc/docblock.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="api-doc/file.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template name="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/project/file[@path=$path]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is a snippet of api-doc/file.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:output indent="no" method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <div class="text-content">
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The element `<div class="text-content"></div>` is what has the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` attribute added to it.

Comment: What does the `xsl:output` look like?  Can you show us some of your XSL?

Comment: @JLRishe I added the contents of one of my .xsl files

Comment: Could you show us what one of those `api-doc` XSLTs looks like? Did you create those or did someone else?  If your result has `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` in it, then no amount of namespace prefix excluding will remove that because the result is actually using that namespace.

Comment: @JLRishe i added the content of api-doc/file.xsl, I did create that file as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Michael Kay said, if you don't want the `div` in the xhtml namespace, remove the default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`) from your `xsl:stylesheet`.

Otherwise you could build the element using `xsl:element` and give it an empty namespace:

```
    <xsl:element name="div" namespace="">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">text-content</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<div>` literal result element in your sample is in the namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml. If you don't want it in that namespace, then don't put it in that namespace.

Comment: well the `<div>` needs to be there, so how would i do that, just remove the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` from the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element in all my .xsl files? I had just assumed that that "default" namespace would be required.

Comment: Correct! Why are you using that namespace anyway if you don't want elements in that namespace? You seem to want your elements to have no namespace at all--so don't give them a namespace.

Comment: @FrancisAvila To be honest I am deriving my phpdoc template that is using these .xsl files from one of the base templates that come with phpdoc itself, which had was using that namespace in every .xsl file. I don't have alot of experience with XSLT, so I just assumed it was necessary for the template to work properly when being parsed by phpdoc to create the resulting HTML files.

Comment: If phpdoc is generating xhtml to be served as xhtml, then the namespace is necessary or at least not harmful.

Comment: understood. I think the key difference between my template and phpdoc's base template that I used as a starting point is that phpdoc's template was generating complete html files, from `<html>` on down, whereas mine is only generating html fragments meant to be included inside an external application/website. In any  case, just removing the namespace from the `<xsl:stylesheet>` did do the trick, so michael's answer was correct. However I accepted Daniel's answer as he explained the actual course of action to take a bit more thoroughly. :)